# Find the number of (complex) ordered $(z,\omega)$ satisfying $z^3+\bar{\omega}^7=0$ and $z^5\omega^{11} = 1$

Tags: complex-numbers

> Find the number of complex ordered pairs $(z,\omega)$ satisfying
>   $$z^3+\bar{\omega}^7=0 \qquad \textrm{and} \qquad z^5\omega^{11} = 1 .$$

**My try** Given $z^3+\bar{\omega}^7=0\Rightarrow z^3=-\bar{\omega}^7$.

So $|z^3| = |-\bar{\omega}^7|\Rightarrow |z|^3=|\omega|^7$ and given $z^5\omega^{11}=1\;,$ Then $|z|^5|\omega|^{11} = 1$.

How can I solve it after that?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Cubing both sides of the second equation gves
$$1 = z^{15} \omega^{33} = (z^3)^5 \omega^{33} = (-\bar\omega^7)^5 \omega^{33} = -\omega^{33} \bar\omega^{35},$$
and taking the norm of both sides gives $| \omega | = 1$. Taking the norm of both sides of the second given equation then yields $|z| = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

You got most of it already. The only way you can have
$$|z|=|\omega|^{7/3}$$
and
$$|z|=|\omega|^{-11/5}$$
at the same time, is to have $|z|=|w|=1$. Then set $z=e^{i\phi}$ and $w=e^{i\theta}$ and you get

$$e^{3i\phi}=-e^{-7i\theta}$$
and
$$e^{5i\phi}=e^{-11i\theta}$$

The first yields
$$3\phi=-7\theta+\pi i+2k\pi $$
the second
$$5\phi=-11\theta+2n\pi$$
This is a linear problem you can solve yourself.